# Customizing/Modifying the Bootscreen Animation

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to change to boot screen animation to a custom image or screen on Windows 8?

Comment: See this site for more info http://cristalhack.blogspot.ro/2012/09/wanna-change-windows-8-boot-screen.html Boot dll http://browse.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&q=bootres.dll

Answer (score 2):

So far I have not seen a solution where you can change the boot animation. There are changes you can make to the boot screen but replacing it isn't currently possible.

Here's a tool to help: http://www.wesnext.com/visual-boot-experience/

Comment: Okay I take that back. You can replace it but getting your own custom one isn't currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open Windows Explorer, navigate to C:\Windows\Boot folder. Here, “C” is your Windows 8 drive letter.

Step 2: Open Resources folder, rename bootres.dll file to bootresbackup.dll.

Step 3: Copy your new bootres.dll file to C:\Boot\Resources folder.Reboot your PC to see the new boot screen.

Good luck!

Comment: And where do we get the `bootres.dll` file from?

Comment: Customize the .dll for yourself, then you can change to your own bootscreen.

Comment: @SueVilla Do you mind adding instructions for customizing the dll, otherwise your answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article **how to change the boot logo in Windows 8.1 and Windows 8** at

http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-change-the-boot-logo-in-windows-8-1-and-windows-8/

If will also explain **how to create the bootres.dll** file.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.